# Capybara/Poltergeist doesn't keep hovered elements visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, automated-tests, poltergeist

I'm trying to set up a automated test suite using capybara (v 2.4.3) and poltergeist (v 1.5.1)

My Problem is that poltergeist needs to click on a img (which is a link) that is only visible if you hover over another element (see screenshot in link)

[flags exposed](http://i62.tinypic.com/mh4j6p.jpg)

(sorry but I can not upload images yet, so I linked my screenshot above)

I expose those hidden images by using this command:

```
find('div#userlogin div.colorswitch_languageswitch a.btn_earth').hover
```

the whole test looks like this

```
it 'switches language to english', focus: true, js: true do
    find('div#userlogin div.colorswitch_languageswitch a.btn_earth').hover
    save_and_open_screenshot # to ensure the flags are displayed, this works
    within('div#language_flags') do
        click_link('Language_usa') # when I try to click it doesn't switch languages
    end
    page.should have_content('Login name (email)')
    page.should have_content('Forgot password?')
end
```

I've already turned on the debugging feature of poltergeist and it seems that poltergeist is clicking on the right coordinates but doesn't hit the link.

After this I changed the view a bit and removed the "display:none" style attribute, so the images that need to be clicked are always visible. The test now passes.

So my question is: **How do I make poltergeist move the mouse to the images after hovering the parent element like a user would do it, so they don't disappear**

PS: If I've forgotten important information please let me know

Comment: No solutions? I cri evrytiem QQ

Comment: not so far.... I'm using selenium now for this test